# Connect failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)” in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have got error when try to insert data using PHP code to wordpress database.

Error like this :

> Connect failed: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)” in wordpress

How can I fix this.

I'm working on live server.

Comment: you have your database connection credentials setup wrong in `wp-config.php`.

Comment: I have check wp-config file like this :    
$wpconfig = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-config.php';
$contents = file_get_contents( $wpconfig );
foreach ( array( 'DB_NAME', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASSWORD', 'DB_HOST' ) as $config )
@$link = mysql_connect( $DB_HOST[3], $DB_USER[3], $DB_PASSWORD[3] );if ( ! $link ) {
die( sprintf( "Could not connect to the MySQL server: %s\n", mysql_error() ) );}echo "Connected successfully to the MySQL server\n";@$db_selected = mysql_select_db( $DB_NAME[3], $link );
}
echo "Database selected successfully\n";

Comment: Also your earlier post had you connecting to the database as root for your Wordpress operations. This is a bad idea.Create a separate database user and grant rights accordingly.

Comment: my site work fine.but I was create custom table in wordpress database and i have try to insert data using php code. so thats time i got error like above

Comment: Remove ampersands (@) from your code while debugging. They suppress warnings/errors. Also, `$link = mysql_connect( $DB_HOST[3], $DB_USER[3], $DB_PASSWORD[3] );` where are $DB_HOST[3], etc., being set per your comment above? Shouldn't you be using `$config` instead?

Comment: Yes you are right . established connection successfully.Thanks @Marcus

Answer (score 1):

Check your config.php in the main folder and look for this lines if there configure correctly.

```
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Comment: yes it exactly look like but even though error occur .

Comment: well they must be wrong

Comment: I have work in live so i have filled up username and password ..

Comment: check this out https://wordpress.org/support/topic/access-denied-for-user-localhost-using-password-no